# Como Incluir um item em um ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma classe Pessoa que tem um `ICollection` da classe Telefone.
Na tela de manutenção de Pessoa tenho um dataTable com os Telefones. Existe um link para acrescentar um novo telefone, mas não consigo usar o `@Html.DropDownLIstFor` para pedir o tipo de telefone (comercial, residencial, celular).

Vou tentar ser sucinto.

```
public partial class PessoaModel
{
        public Guid PessoaID { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TelefoneModel> Telefone { get; set; }
}
    public partial class TelefoneModel
    {
        public Guid TelefoneID { get; set; }
        public string DDD { get; set; }
        public string Numero { get; set; }
        public string TipoTelefone { get; set; }
        public Guid PessoaID { get; set; }
    }
```

E minha view está desta forma:

```
@model GeoArea.Models.ViewModel.PessoaViewModel

<div class="panel panel-default" id="ITelefones">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Telefones</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table id="tbTelefonePessoa" class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Opções</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>

        <div style="text-align:end">
            <a href="#" onclick="AcrescentarFone()">acrescentar  telefone</a>
        </div>
        <div id="acrescfone" class="hidden">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.Label("Tipo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone.FirstOrDefault().TipoTelefone.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.Label("Telefone", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefone.FirstOrDefault().Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ex = document.getElementById('tbTelefonePessoa');
        if ($.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(ex)) {
            $(ex).dataTable().fnClearTable();
            $(ex).dataTable().fnDraw();
        }
        oTelefonePessoa = $('#tbTelefonePessoa').DataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "dom": '<"hidden"f><"hidden"l><"hidden"i><"hidden"p>t',
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bStateSave": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "sSearch": false,
            "destroy": true,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "bSort": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "order": [[0, "asc"]],
            "language": {
                "url": ROOT + "Content/resources/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    'targets': 1,
                    "mData": 0,
                     mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                         var fone = row["Numero"];
                         fone = '(' + row["DDD"] + ') ' + fone.substr(0,(fone.length - 4)) + '-' + fone.substr((fone.length - 4),4);
                        return fone;
                    }
                },
                {
                    'targets': 2,
                    mRender: function(){
                        return '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">alterar</a>' + '   ' +
                               '<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">excluir</a>';
                    }
                }
            ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "TipoTelefone.Nome" },
                { "data": "DDD" },
                { "data": "Numero" }
            ]
        });

        var data = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Telefone));
        if (data.length > 0) {
            $("#tbTelefonePessoa").dataTable().fnAddData(data);
        }
    });

    function AcrescentarFone(){
        $("#acrescfone").removeClass("hidden");
    };
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Não preciso necessariamente usar o dataTable mas eu achei o mais fácil. Tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tente melhorar sua pergunta, talvez disponibilizando trechos de código que você já tenha mexido.

Comment: Você necessariamente precisar usar o jQuery Datatables? Ou pode substituir por outra coisa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) para realizar isso. Respondo isso algumas vezes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20615+begincollectionitem).

Para utilizar ele você deverá instalar o pacote via Nuget com o seguinte comando:

> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem

Após isso, adicionaremos uma `Action` em seu controller para adicionar um novo telefone à Pessoa, desta forma:

```
public ActionResult GetNewTelefone()
    {
        var telefone = new Telefone
        {
            TelefoneId = Guid.NewGuid()
        };

        return PartialView("_Telefone", telefone);
    }
```

Desta forma estamos criando um novo telefone e retornando o mesmo em uma `PartialView`, que você poderá fazer assim:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Telefone


@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TelefoneId)
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DDD, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DDD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DDD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Numero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Numero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

Dentro do `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Telefones"))` você coloca o nome de soa `ICollection`, que no seu caso seria **Telefone**.

Feito isso, precisamos apenas fazer uma requisição `Ajax` e retornar a `PartialView` para o local desejado, desta forma:

```
<script>
        $('#add-telefone').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetNewTelefone","Pessoa")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#new-telefone').append(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

O Script está fazendo uma requisição ao clicar no botão com o `id=add-telefone` e retornando a `PartialView` para a `div` que tenha o `id=new-telefone`.

Feito isto, basta clicar em salvar normalmente que a lista será enviada ao seu controller.

E em seu controller você salva o telefone normalmente, desta forma:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PessoaId,Nome,Telefones")] Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (pessoa.Telefones != null && pessoa.Telefones.Any())
            {
                foreach (var telefone in pessoa.Telefones)
                {
                    telefone.PessoaId = pessoa.PessoaId;
                    db.Telefone.Add(telefone);
                }
            }

            db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(pessoa);
    }
```

> Se estiver utilizando o [Bind(Include)], não esqueça de adicionar o `ICollection<Telefone> Telefone` nele, senão o valor irá null.

Qualquer dúvida, eu fiz um projeto de exemplo com a utilização deste pacote. Você pode baixar para entender melhor, caso queira. Ele está [em meu GitHub](https://github.com/renilsonmeneguci/Ajuda-BeginCollectionItem).

Answer (score 0):

Um tipo ICollection é apenas a amostragem de uma coleção(readonly), sendo List, uma implementação de IList, que vem de ICollection, junto com metodos de manipulação de lista(ex: Add, Remove, Clear).

Utilize da seguinte maneira:

```
public virtual List<TelefoneModel> Telefone { get; set; }
```