# ASP.NET MVC Calcular valor em uma tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo um cadastro onde terei uma `table` com alguns detalhes adicionais que devem ser inseridos juntos com o cadastro principal.

Porém uma das colunas dessa `table` é calculado, que é onde estou tendo dificuldades em realizar esse calculo.

Basicamente, preciso calcular o campo `ValorCalculado` com base no `Percentual` aplicado sobre o `ValorPrincipal`

> **E esse valor deve aparecer conforme o usuário vai digitando o campo ValorPrincipal ou o Percentual**

Sim, fiz um exemplo muito simplório, pensem em um sistema de entrada de produtos em estoque, onde o usuário fez a leitura de um XML e essa nota tem ao menos uns 10 produtos, e está lançando o percentual de lucro  de produto por produto e querendo ver qual o valor de venda a medida que vai alterando esses itens. Imagina ter que estar fazendo uma requisição ao server toda vez que tem um percentual alterado na View, então por isso seria bom fazer o calculo seja na View também e não só no server.

Resumindo, eu preciso que o ValorCalculado apresente o ValorPrincipal*Percentual toda vez que tiver uma alteração no ValorPrincipal ou no Percentual

Segue código de exemplo

```
    public class CadastroController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Cadastro
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CadastroViewModel model = new CadastroViewModel();

            model.Detalhes.Add(new CadastroDetalhesViewModel());
            model.Detalhes.Add(new CadastroDetalhesViewModel());
            model.Detalhes.Add(new CadastroDetalhesViewModel());
            model.Detalhes.Add(new CadastroDetalhesViewModel());

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CadastroViewModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Model

```
    public class CadastroViewModel
    {
        public CadastroViewModel()
        {
            Detalhes = new List<CadastroDetalhesViewModel>();
        }

        public int CadastroId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataFim { get; set; }

        public decimal ValorPrincipal { get; set; }

        public decimal Percentual { get; set; }

        public decimal ValorCalculado { get; set; }

        public List<CadastroDetalhesViewModel> Detalhes { get; set; }
    }

    public class CadastroDetalhesViewModel
    {
        public int CadastroId { get; set; }

        public decimal ValorPrincipal { get; set; }

        public decimal Percentual { get; set; }

        public decimal ValorCalculado { get; set; }

    }
```

View

```
@model AspNetMvcCalcularValoresTabela.Models.CadastroViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CadastroViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CadastroId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CadastroId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CadastroId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataFim, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFim, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataFim, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorPrincipal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValorPrincipal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValorPrincipal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Percentual, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Percentual, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Percentual, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorCalculado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValorCalculado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValorCalculado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Detalhes.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Detalhes[i].ValorPrincipal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Detalhes[i].Percentual, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                        <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Detalhes[i].ValorCalculado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Se me permitir, utilizarei `foreach` para a resposta.

Basta fazer o calculo no laço mesmo, exemplo:

```
 <tbody>
  @foreach(var item in Model.Detalhes)
  {
    //Não sei qual a regra que você precisa, então farei uma multiplicação, mas altere para sua encessidade.
    item.ValorCalculado = item.ValorPrincipal * item.ValorCalculado; 

      <tr>
          <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => item.ValorPrincipal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
          <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => item.Percentual, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
          <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => item.ValorCalculado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
      </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

E pelo que vejo, está enviando esses valores para um controller, aconselho usar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114133/20615).

Agora, se quiser continuar usando o `for`, basta seguir a mesma lógica:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Detalhes.Count; i++)
    {
        Model.Detalhes[i].ValorCalculado = Model.Detalhes[i].ValorPrincipal * Model.Detalhes[i].Percentual;
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Detalhes[i].ValorPrincipal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Detalhes[i].Percentual, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(a => a.Detalhes[i].ValorCalculado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

> Não entendi a razão de você fazer o calculo por meio de um valor digitado na `View`. Se o sistema deve gerar, seria melhor fazer isso no `server`, seria mais "seguro" o calculo.

### Edição

> Com base nos comentários do AP, adicionarei uma resposta alternativa em jQuery.

Para fazer o que deseja, vamos utilizar o evento [.blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) do jQuery para alterar o valor do `ValorCalculado` sempre que o valor de um `input` for alterado, desta forma:

```js
$('input').blur(function(){

 var valorPrincipal = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id*="ValorPrincipal"]').first().val();
 var percentual = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id*="Percentual"]').first().val();
  var valorCalculado = valorPrincipal * percentual;
  
  if(valorCalculado != 0){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id*="ValorCalculado"]').first().val(valorCalculado);
  }else{
   $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id*="ValorCalculado"]').first().val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>Valor Principal</tr>
  <tr> Percentual</tr>
  <tr> Valor Calculado</tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ValorPrincipal1"/></td>
        <td><input id="Percentual1"/></td>
        <td><input id="ValorCalculado1"/></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input id="ValorPrincipal2"/></td>
        <td><input id="Percentual2"/></td>
        <td><input id="ValorCalculado2"/></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
        <td><input id="ValorPrincipal3"/></td>
        <td><input id="Percentual3"/></td>
        <td><input id="ValorCalculado3"/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/048o9quq/)

**Explicando o que foi feito:**

A explicação é bem simples. Sempre que um `input` for alterado e o `focus` sair dele, ou seja sair do `input`, será calculado o novo valor do `ValorCalculado` referente a linha na tabela. Para isso, é preciso obter os valores Pricipal e Percentual, da mesma linha. Esta linha de código faz esse trabalho:

```
var valorPrincipal = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id*="ValorPrincipal"]').first().val();
```

Onde `$(this)` é o elemento que `input` que o usuário editou, `.parent().parent()` é responsável por obter o `tr` de cada linha,`.find('input[id*="ValorPrincipal"]').first().val()` é responsável por buscar o elemento que contenha `ValorPrincipal` no **id** (certifique que tenha isso no id, ou altere para o que achar melhor) e obter o seu valor. Feito isso, basta replicar para a porcentagem, fazer o cálculo de devolver o valor ao `input` correspondente, como mostrado no exemplo.

Comment: Sim, fiz um exemplo muito simplório, pensa em um sistema de entrada de produtos em estoque, onde o usuário está lançando o percentual de lucro  de produto por produto e querendo ver qual o valor de venda a medida que vai alterando esses itens. Imagina ter que estar fazendo uma requisição ao server toda vez que tem um percentual alterado na View, então por isso que preciso que o calculo seja na View também e não só no server.

Comment: @PabloVargas Mas se o usuário irá digitar o valor calculado, não faz sentido de ter que calcular o mesmo, a não ser se for validações. Agora, se esse calculo será gerado automaticamente na view apenas para auxiliar, ok. Porém, se precisa desse valor preciso, o ideal é fazer uma requisição ao server em cada alteração sim, mesmo que seja na view, por ajax ou jQuery.

Comment: @PabloVargas Se preza segurança, não deve deixar na view qualquer informação que não possa ser alterada. Mas isso entramos em outros fatores. Me avise se a resposta não lhe ajudar

Comment: te entando, mas o `ValorCalculado` não será digitado pelo usuário, será um campo de auxílio do calculo do ValorPrincipal*Percentual.

Comment: @PabloVargas Mas estando na `View` ele é passível de alteração. Mas como você disse, você fez um exemplo simplório, então não posso afirmar nada sobre seu código.

Comment: Resumindo, eu preciso que o ValorCalculado apresente o ValorPrincipal*Percentual toda vez que tiver uma alteração no ValorPrincipal ou no Percentual

Comment: @PabloVargas Bom, fiz das duas formas, basta testar e me dizer se lhe ajuda.

Comment: não ajuda, pois o seu exemplo teria que vir com os valores já informados do servidor para a view, o que eu quero é que na medida que os valores vão sendo digitados, vá sendo calculado o valor

Comment: @PabloVargas Então você precisa de algo com javascript ou jQuery, o que não está especificado na pergunta. Se não tiver a resposta que procura, amanhã eu altero da forma que precisa.

Comment: Blz, fico no aguardo

Comment: @PabloVargas Veja se lhe atende agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39019/discussion-between-pablo-vargas-and-randrade).